# select2 not displaying returned json results

Tags: html, json, ajax, jquery-select2

I have copied the ajax data loading code from [select2 documentation](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-ajax) into my html page. When I type I can see the results are loading in network call as shown below

[image: loaded results in network call]

but results are not showing in a dropdown as below picture shows. It only shows `Loading more results` text.

[image: select drop down menu]

I checked in generated html code by inspect elements. I saw a bunch of list items with `style="display: none;"` and there was no text in list items either. One list item was as below

```
<li class="select2-results__option" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false" style="display: none;"></li>
```

Are there any issue with the code provided in documentation or any change need to make the result list visible?

Comment: is there an error in the console log

Comment: no there is no any error in console log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29807324/select2-loading-remote-data-example-not-working). I need to define `formatRepo` and `formatRepoSelection` functions.